# Multiuser Communication with Javascript

Tags: javascript, client, multi-user

Can anyone recommend me links or books to build a multiuser application? My idea is an web app, with which users can play multiuser game on their browsers. I also want to create an app with phonegap, which should run on iphone and android too.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend looking into using node.js with Socket.io for this.